how to set persian language to flutter_tts package
I am going to change the text to voice in flutter and I'm installed flutterTts package so its just read English text and its unable to read Persian language.
I also set the language to
flutterTts.setLanguage('fa-IR') 

but still doesn't work.
here is my code...
class _AdditionState extends State<Addition> {
  final FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
  String text = '';

  Future<void> _speak() async {
    await flutterTts.setLanguage('fa-IR'); // Set language to Persian (fa-IR)
    await flutterTts.speak(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text to Speech'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  text = value;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter text to speak',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _speak();
              },
              child: Text('Speak'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The library utilizes the TTS engine of the device, if it doesn't work it is likely that your device doesn't support it.
If you're using Android, minimum SDK version is 21.
For OSX it's 10.5.
Check out their repo for more details. https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts
